# ExtJS 5: How do I include text after a numberfield?

Tags: extjs, label

Just about every field has a fieldLabel and a boxLabel config to set text either before or after the field. However, number field just happens to be one of them that does not. Is there anyway I can set text after a number field?
Example:

[ 1  ^] text goes here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this did the trick

```
afterSubTpl: 'this is after'
```

However it appears below the numberfield instead of directly to the right. 
And this

```
beforeSubTpl: 'this is before'
```

puts the text above it, instead of to the left.

Working seeing if this can be fixed with styling.